# Mockito :: how to mockSimpleDateFormat.parse() in Dao

Tags: java, mockito

I'm new to Java / Mockito and trying to test a Dao method, specifically an exception condition that catches ParseException and throws SQLException.

Here's the Dao code:

```
public Template saveTemplate(Template template) throws SQLException {
    logger.debug("Saving template details into the db ", template.getTemplateName());

    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Long date = 0L;
    try {
        date = dt.parse(template.getStartTime()).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new SQLException("Error while processing date " + template.getTemplateName());
    }

    Long finalDate = date;
```

My strategy was to mock the `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` call so that it throws the ParseException, but that's not working. Not even sure that's a good strategy...

First I tried:

```
@InjectMocks private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat;
```

but that doesn't work because the SimpleDateFormat constructor requires a parameter, and gets the error:

`org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'simpleDateFormat' of type 'class java.text.SimpleDateFormat'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : null`

So then I tried this:

```
@Mock
private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
@Test(expected = SQLException.class)
public void test_save_template_date_parse_error() throws ParseException, SQLException {
  initMocks(this);
  Mockito.mockingDetails(simpleDateFormat);
  Mockito.when(simpleDateFormat.parse(anyString(),new ParsePosition(anyInt()))).thenThrow(new ParseException(anyString(),anyInt()));

    Template template = new Template();
    template.setStartTime("2017-01-02 12:12:12");
    template.setTemplateId(1);
    given(jdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations()).willReturn(jdbcOperations);
    templateDAOImpl.saveTemplate(template);
}
```

The resulting error isn't helpful to my unpracticed eye:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at com.macys.etap.ee.dao.TemplateDAOImplTest.test_save_template_date_parse_error(TemplateDAOImplTest.java:77)
-> at com.macys.etap.ee.dao.TemplateDAOImplTest.test_save_template_date_parse_error(TemplateDAOImplTest.java:77)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

So how do I mock this thing and get the error thrown?

**Edit: New approach as suggested, mocking Template.getStartTime():**

    `@Test(expected = SQLException.class)
    public void test_save_template_date_parse_error() throws ParseException, SQLException {
      initMocks(this);
      Template templateMock = Mockito.mock(Template.class);
      Mockito.when(templateMock.getStartTime()).thenReturn("invalid");
      Mockito.mockingDetails(templateMock.getStartTime());
      Template template = new Template();
      template.setStartTime("2017-01-02 12:12:12");
      template.setTemplateId(1);
      given(jdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations()).willReturn(jdbcOperations);
      // Fixed per @Daniel Pryden : works now
      templateDAOImpl.saveTemplate(templateMock); 
    }`

And now works with the fix.

Comment: Why are you trying to mock `SimpleDateFormat` at all? Just mock out `Template.getStartTime()` to return something that isn't a date, and that will cause a `ParseException` to get thrown "naturally".

Comment: Tried `Mockito.when(template.getStartTime()).thenReturn("invalid');` but that didn't do anything - the `dt.parse()` method still worked normally.

Comment: That's surprising: `SimpleDateFormat` is specified to throw `ParseException` if the date cannot be parsed. Can you create an [mcve] to demonstrate that and add it into your question?

Comment: Oh wait, are you calling `Mockito.when()` on a `Template` object you constructed with `new Template()`? That won't work: `when()` needs a mock object. Use `Template template = Mockito.mock(Template.class);` instead.

Comment: I added `@Mock Template template;` before my test; I thought that was the same thing? But I'll try it explicitly like you say.

Comment: It's the same thing as long as you don't overwrite the `template` field with a different object, or shadow the reference with a new local variable.

Comment: OK... I changed it to `Template templateMock = Mockito.mock(Template.class);` followed by the `when()` clause, and then the test run which does instantiate `new Template()`. But dt.parse() still refuses to fail. I'll update the question so it's all in one place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171258/discussion-between-jesii-and-daniel-pryden).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocks aren't magic. They're just objects, and so they obey the same rules as all other objects in the Java language. Most importantly: mock objects don't magically take the place of real objects. You need to pass a reference to the mock instead of a reference to the real object.

In your updated question, you show this code:

```
  Template templateMock = Mockito.mock(Template.class);
  Mockito.when(templateMock...)...
  Template template = new Template();
  ...
  templateDAOImpl.saveTemplate(template);
```

That is: you're setting up an object called `templateMock` which has type `Template` and is configured with the behavior you want, but then the object you actually pass into `templateDAOImpl.saveTemplate` is not that object!

This means that all your code setting up the `templateMock` is effectively dead code: since the value you pass into `saveTemplate` was constructed using `new Template()` then it is not a mock.

More generally: Mockito never does anything that you couldn't do by yourself. For example, in this case, you could simply make your own subclass of `Template`:

```
private static class FakeTemplate extends Template {
    @Override
    public String getStartTime() {
        return "invalid date";
    }

    // override other methods as necessary/desired
}

// in your test:
Template fakeTemplate = new FakeTemplate();
templateDAOImpl.saveTemplate(fakeTemplate);
```

That is all that Mockito is doing when you mock out `Template`. Mockito just does it in a "fancier" way so that you have less boilerplate code to write. But if you don't understand what Mockito is doing then you shouldn't feel compelled to use it. Always write code you *understand*, and then you'll always be able to debug it if something goes wrong.

(Aside: There *are* dirty hacks that can make the `new` operator instantiate something different than what it was compiled to do -- and that's how PowerMockito does its "magic" -- but that's never necessary and I would never recommend it.)

Comment: Yep; you're right about passing in the wrong variable; I fixed that. And I did get something to work, although I wound up doing it slightly differently. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you don't even need Mockito here, you can simply do the following :

```
 Template template = new Template();
 template.setStartTime("THIS IS AN INVALID DATE");
 template.setTemplateId(1);
 templateDAOImpl.saveTemplate(template);
```

And then the SQLException will be thrown.

Comment: Tried that; get an assertionError before the code  I want to test. With the update suggested by @Daniel, it's now working with the Mock. thanks

Answer (score 1):

SimpleDateFormat cannot be mocked at all, because you are creating a new instance inside a method, so the mock will be never applied.

Possibilities:

- change class structure (e.g put SimpleDateFormat as a constuctor parameter, then InjectMocks annotation will work)
- pass invalid data for parse method to break it
- use PowerMockito whenNew method, however it should be finality

Comment: Changed as noted in the update to mock Template.getStartTime() and now working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I found another way to implement this requirement where I used a spy and mocked pretty much everything out; it may help someone else.

```
@InjectMocks
final Template partiallyMockedTemplate = spy(new Template());

@Test(expected = SQLException.class)
public void test_save_template_date_parse_error() throws SQLException {
  initMocks(this);
    Template template = new Template();
    doReturn("2018-05-44").when(partiallyMockedTemplate).getStartTime();
    partiallyMockedTemplate.setStartTime("2017-01-02 12:12:12");
    partiallyMockedTemplate.setTemplateId(1);
    given(jdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations()).willReturn(jdbcOperations);
    templateDAOImpl.saveTemplate(partiallyMockedTemplate);
}
```